# Mongdb aggregate do second group inside first group stage output

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I don't know if it's either possible but I would like to obtain a specific output from an aggregate pipeline.

Exemples objects:

```
{
  "_id": "6001d736e6dc1c55e893158d",
  "manager": "6000da590ed6253807158216",
  "label": "Test",
  "identifier": "Test",
  "interval": 11,
  "unit": "X",
  "created_at": "2021-01-15T17:56:06.749Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-01-21T12:21:35.670Z",
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": "6030236f976756b0b2d74556",
  "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
  "label": "Temperature salon",
  "identifier": "DS18B20_TEMP",
  "interval": 60,
  "unit": "°C",
  "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:35.847Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:35.847Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I'm trying to obtain a group by date AND by unit(field in object), i succeed to do it separatly but i can't find a solution to do both in the same pipeline.

Expected output if i do the first group by month:

```
{
  "_id": "2021-01-00T00:00:00.000Z",
  "X": objectsArray[],
  "°C": objetcsArray[]
},
{
  "_id": "2021-02-00T00:00:00.000Z",
  "X": objectsArray[],
  "°C": objetcsArray[]
}
```

What i have for the moment with this group:

```
{
    '_id': {
        '$add': [
        { '$subtract': [
            { '$subtract': [ '$created_at', new Date(0) ] },
            { '$mod': [
                { '$subtract': [ '$created_at', new Date(0) ] },
                this.millisecondsIn(interval),
                ]},
            ]},
        new Date(0),
        ]
    },
    sensors: {
        $addToSet: '$$ROOT',
    },
}
```

```
  {
    "_id": "2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "sensors": [
      {
        "_id": "601ab8f623224a5387c6252d",
        "manager": "6000da590ed6253807158216",
        "label": "Test",
        "identifier": "Test2",
        "interval": 60,
        "unit": "°C",
        "created_at": "2021-02-03T14:53:42.538Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-03T14:53:42.538Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "6029ad3dda9bafb99cf0b4d5",
        "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
        "label": "Test sensor 1",
        "identifier": "RANDOMID",
        "interval": 60,
        "unit": "°C",
        "created_at": "2021-02-14T23:07:41.255Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-14T23:07:41.255Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2020-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "sensors": [
      {
        "_id": "6001917f41c38212a477a2ce",
        "manager": "6000da590ed6253807158216",
        "label": "Test label",
        "identifier": "TEst id",
        "interval": 10,
        "unit": "%",
        "created_at": "2021-01-15T12:58:39.514Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-16T19:08:40.239Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "6001d736e6dc1c55e893158d",
        "manager": "6000da590ed6253807158216",
        "label": "Test",
        "identifier": "Test",
        "interval": 11,
        "unit": "X",
        "created_at": "2021-01-15T17:56:06.749Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-21T12:21:35.670Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2021-02-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "sensors": [
      {
        "_id": "6030238d976756b0b2d74557",
        "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
        "label": "Taux d'humidité salon",
        "identifier": "DHT_22_HUM",
        "interval": 60,
        "unit": "%",
        "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:46:05.042Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-19T20:46:05.042Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "60302357976756b0b2d74555",
        "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
        "label": "Temperature salon",
        "identifier": "DTH_22_TEMP",
        "interval": 60,
        "unit": "°C",
        "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:11.071Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:11.071Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "6030236f976756b0b2d74556",
        "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
        "label": "Temperature salon",
        "identifier": "DS18B20_TEMP",
        "interval": 60,
        "unit": "°C",
        "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:35.847Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-19T20:45:35.847Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

Does anyone know if the wanted output is possible and if it is, how ?

Thanks

Comment: Will the units always be one of `X`, `°C`, or `%`, or might there be others?

Comment: There be others, but if it's a big problem, I can do a another request first to retrieve all units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general steps would be:

- $group by `unit` and `date`, pushing all of the documents into a sensors array
- $project to create a new field with {k: <unit value>, v: <sensors array>}
- $group by date, pushing the new field into an array
- $project with $arrayToObject to convert array
- $addFields to include the date in the new object
- $replaceRoot to promote the new object

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe), after few hours and many tries I end up with this:

```
this.sensorModel
  .aggregate()
  .group({
    '_id': {
      date: { '$year': '$created_at' },
      'unit': '$unit',
    },
    test: { '$addToSet': '$$ROOT' },
  })
  .project({
    newField: {
      k: '$_id.unit',
      v: '$test',
    }
  })
  .group({
    '_id': '$_id.date',
    data: { '$addToSet': '$newField', },
  })
  .project({
    'sensors': { $arrayToObject: '$data', },
  })
  .replaceRoot({
    $arrayToObject: [[{k: {$toString: '$_id'}, v: '$sensors'}]]
  })
  .exec();
```

The result is almost perfect:

```
[
  {
    "2021": {
      "°C": [
        {
          "_id": "6029ad3dda9bafb99cf0b4d5",
          "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
          "label": "Test sensor 1",
          "identifier": "RANDOMID",
          "interval": 60,
          "unit": "°C",
          "created_at": "2021-02-14T23:07:41.255Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-02-14T23:07:41.255Z",
          "__v": 0
        },
      ],
      "X": [
        {
          "_id": "6001d736e6dc1c55e893158d",
          "manager": "6000da590ed6253807158216",
          "label": "Test",
          "identifier": "Test",
          "interval": 11,
          "unit": "X",
          "created_at": "2021-01-15T17:56:06.749Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-01-21T12:21:35.670Z",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ],
      "%": [
        {
          "_id": "6030238d976756b0b2d74557",
          "manager": "6022f3285752fec73393bda2",
          "label": "Taux d'humidité salon",
          "identifier": "DHT_22_HUM",
          "interval": 60,
          "unit": "%",
          "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:46:05.042Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-02-19T20:46:05.042Z",
          "__v": 0
        },
      ]
    }
  }
]
```